# How to count changes between two nested (hierarchical) collections?

Tags: c#, collections, hierarchy

I have a hierarchical taxonomy of **Terms**, each Term having a GUID and a text Label.

```
class Term
{
  Guid TermId;
  String Label;
  Guid ParentTermId;
  IEnumerable<Term> Children
}
```

This can go N-Levels deep (there are no hard limits on the number of levels of "children" we can have, although realistically there would be no more than 10 or 12 levels, depending on the root term).

I need to compare collections of Terms (both with their own children, grandchildren and so on) and what I need is the **number of changes**.

This includes

- New Terms
- Removed (missing) Terms
- Changes to a Term's Label (i.e. the GUID is the same, but the label is different)
- Terms which have MOVED (i.e. the GUID is the same, but they now have a different parent)

So .. what is the simplest way of doing this, without a significant impact on performance?

```
List<Term> originalTerms = GetTermsFromDatabase();
List<Term> newTerms = GetTermsFromFile();

// What should this "GetCountOfChanges" method look like?
int changes = GetCountOfChanges(originalTerms, newTerms);
```

Comment: I think you can build up a Dictionary out of the original terms using TermId as key in O(n). After that you can iterate over newTerms and try find the item in the dict. If it's not present - it's new. If present, compare both for equality and delete it from dict. This should also take O(n). After that all pressent items in dict are deleted. The whole operation is O(n). Hope that helps.

Comment: please supply some example data and also what you have tried?... This site is to help you with specific problems you got and not writing the code for you (this question might be closed on "too broad"...)

Comment: The existing implementation is a WAAAAY over the top (over-engineered) solution using about a dozen different classes and factory methods. I like Vera's dictionary method. Might give that a go!

Comment: as in ... I'll get back with code samples if that doesn't work out too well

Comment: @MartinHatch Have you looked into something like [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54245/comparing-two-tree-structures)?

Comment: @galenus OP don't want to compare tree structures. There are only the label and parent to compare (children are indirectly compared by parent if the structure is guaranteed to be valid). But it's a good link to be stored in my favorites :-) Martin: correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Verarind I guess the above structure could be easily represented as a tree, and then existing tree comparison algorithms will be applicable to the problem.